# net and netstat command alternative in wmic

Tags: windows, cmd, wmic

Are there any alternative to **net accounts** and **netstat** commands in wmic? Or is it possible to make their output **CSV** like (for example **wmic cpu list /format:csv** )

Comment: *"[Beginning in 2012, WMIC is deprecated in favor of PowerShell cmdlets which perform equivalent CIM operations, such as get-wmiobject, invoke-wmimethod, Get-wmiobject, and gwmi.](https://www.computerhope.com/wmic.htm)"*

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic path Win32_Account get /format:csv

wmic path Win32_Group get /format:csv

wmic path Win32_GroupInDomain get /format:csv

wmic path Win32_GroupUser get /format:csv

wmic path Win32_SystemAccount get /format:csv

wmic path Win32_SystemUsers get /format:csv

wmic path Win32_UserAccount get /format:csv
```

### .